# IE10 local page won't open CSS

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Just installed IE10, and even with a "default reset," when I open a local page (like C:\Documents\index.html), it refuses to load a simple linked stylesheet, with a straightforward call like:

```
<link href='common.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

The console error message is: **SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch**

I've hunted through the security settings, but nothing seems to change the behavior.

Viewing the page from the web, there's no problem, of course.

Anyone have a clue?

(FWIW, I'm seeing exactly the same problem on a Win7/64 desktop machine and on an aging little Win7/32 netbook.)

Edit: Here's a simple test case. Save this HTML as index.html in a folder on your PC:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Basic</title>
<link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<p>This text should be red.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now save this CSS in the same folder, as common.css:

```
body {
    color: red;
}
```

Open index.html with Firefox or Chrome - red text, right? But if I open it with IE10, the text is black - the common.css file is not being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

It's OK to use the Control Panel "Default Programs / Associate a file type..." to set .css files to be opened by Notetab Light (my favorite general-purpose text editor). However, if you go into Notetab Light itself and choose View, Options, Associations, and add css to the list, this generates the error I've been seeing.

Apparently, this is producing a registry entry that causes IE10 to be unable to open a local CSS file when it's called from an HTML page. IE9 wasn't afflicted by this (I never had a problem before, and I've been using Notetab Light for ages).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, helped me solve similar issue for our customers

Comment: Glad it helped - I've heard of similar problems with other applications that associate themselves with certain file types. I wish I knew exactly what registry entry or entries were involved in triggering the problem, but it's too tough to sift through.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it easily with a few steps:

1. Run -> regedit
2. Open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.css
3. Modify: "Content Type" from "text/plain" to "text/css"
4. Exit regedit

IE 10 now properly reads local CSS files.

Comment: @Danny No problem. I was scratching my head when I saw it too. Not sure I understand the rationale behind that functionality. Perhaps it was just a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Due to MIME type mismatch css was ignored in ie 10. The MIME type can be correct by a utility called [FIle TypesMan](http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) It is freeware created by NirSoft. It turned out that the MIME type of .css had been changed to text/plain, preventing ie from rendering my styles. using FileTypesMan to change it back to text/css fixed the problem.
Download FileTypesMan from the NirSoft site. Use the links near the bottom of the page to select the correct version for your operating system (there are different versions for 32-bit, 64-bit, and Windows 98/ME).
Unzip the files to a local folder, and double-click FileTypesMan.exe.
When FileTypesMan has finished listing all file types, scroll down in the top pane to find .css.
Double-click to edit the settings.
Change the value to text/css in the MIME Type field in the dialog box that opens.
Click OK. Job done. IE 10 should now behave itself (well, at least as far as rendering style sheets is concerned).