# css was ignored due to mime type mismatch ie 11 on server

Tags: html, css, jsp, mime-types

I have a web application where i used css and jsp pages.That application runs completely fine on my local machine. but when i deploy it on server my css is not loading properly and giving error like "css was ignored due to mime type mismatch IE-11".I searched it but not getting correct answer.I tried by changing the content type to "text/css" but it don't work.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Post the generated HTML or even better, setup a jsFiddle with the HTML showing the error.

Comment: you can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974731/css-not-rendered-in-ie-10) and you can also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654503/ie10-local-page-wont-open-css/22086837#22086837)